# How to print Polars dataframe without the leading 'shape' information

Tags: python, dataframe, printing

When I print a Polars dataframe (e.g., from terminal or within Jupyter notebook), there is a leading string citing the shape of the resultant dataframe. I am looking for the method to not have this printed as part of the result.

The simple example would be the following:

```
>>> import polars as pl
>>> df = pl.DataFrame()
>>> df
shape: (0, 0)
┌┐
╞╡
└┘
>>> print(df)
shape: (0, 0)
┌┐
╞╡
└┘
>>> print(df[0, :])
shape: (0, 0)
┌┐
╞╡
└┘
```

My question is how would I print only the dataframe without the lurking "shape: [n, m]" string?

Comment: Not nice, but seems to work: `print(str(df).split("\n", 1)[1])`

Comment: @Timus, that is the only route I can come up with, as well. But I feel that there has to be a Polars-intrinsic way to mute that portion of the output. But thank you for the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found a *native* way: you could use [`pl.Config.set_tbl_hide_dataframe_shape`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.Config.set_tbl_hide_dataframe_shape.html). This

```py
import polars as pl

pl.Config.set_tbl_hide_dataframe_shape(True)

df = pl.DataFrame({'col1': range(3), 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
print(df)
```

results in

```
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col2 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ a    │
│ 1    ┆ b    │
│ 2    ┆ c    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: This would seem to be the correct answer. Many thanks to you, @Timus!

Comment: Note that this breaks if the `df` is inside a dictionary since the shape adds a line break: https://i.imgur.com/1QowpWZ.png